# PiFace Digital2 and LED display

Tags: pi-3, gpio, display, piface

I'm building a home alarm system with Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and the PiFace Digital 2 board. 
I will have used all 8 inputs, and maybe 4 outputs.

Now, my question is, If I would like to connect a 16x2 LED display sitting in hallway, (RPi will be in the technical room) is there a possibility to connect it? Because all the GPIO pins are already used by PiFace and I've searched, but couldn't find an extension board, which would allow me to use PiFace Digital + GPIO pins.

do you have any idea, how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean LCD 16 x 2?  You can easily find I2C LCD16x2.  So you don't need any extra pins.

Comment: I know, but currently all my PINs are used by the PiFace Digital 2.
so currently, it looks like this: https://www.kiwi-electronics.nl/image/cache/data/products/raspberry-pi/gpio/RPI-PF2-3-1000x667.jpg

Comment: I see.  So you hat is not stackable.  One solution is to get something like this, to expand one row of GPIO pins to three rows - https://www.amazon.com/Electronics-Salon-Expansion-Extension-Module-Raspberry/dp/B07C9MTCRQ.  Another get around is solder three I2C signal wires (SCL, SDA, Gnd) from the HAT's 40 pin connector.